# How to correctly use inverse clipping on objects in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

I'm trying to remove part of a graphic using clipping in Inkscape, but I can't manage to do it.
I've tried all the options under `Object > Clip` and `Object > Mask`

The picture below illustrates the problem I have.
[image]

- I start with the image on the left.
- The middle one is the result after clipping/masking (all the options give the same result )
- On the right is what I want (I just changed the background color of the rectangle)

**Note :** I'm using **Inkscape 1.0.1**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you want to use *Object > Clip > Set inverse (LPE)*. The only thing is that it doesn't work properly on a text object because it isn't a path. However, you can convert the text to paths using *Path > Object to Path*, then the inverse clip should work.

Here's an example

[image]

If you want to mask editable text, then you'll need a different approach.  In the example below I grouped a black rectangle, and a larger white rectangle behind it, to use as a mask. Place it over the text, select all and do *Object > Mask > Set*.  Here the text remains as an editable text object.

Example

[image]